# find attribute value using element value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

following is my XML where i need to find Changeset attribute value of (Id) using `<id>` value of `<task>/id` value using Xpath.

i have tried the followin query `"ReleaseNotes/ChangeSets/ChangeSet[Comments/checkintext/task/id ='" + jiraId + "']"` where jiraId is `<task>id` value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReleaseNotes>
    <AxVersion>6.2.1000.1437</AxVersion>
    <FromDate>2/1/2015 12:00:00 AM</FromDate>
    <ToDate>2/26/2015 12:00:00 AM</ToDate>
    <ChangeSets>
        <ChangeSet Id="3600">
            <CheckInUserId>XXX\yy</CheckInUserId>
            <Comments>
                <checkintext>
                    <bpcheckdeviated>true</bpcheckdeviated>
                    <task>
                        <id>CS-2215</id>
                        <name>Small performance improvements in hedge qty lookup.</name>
                        <version>V6.0</version>
                        <sprint>17.8</sprint>
                        <project>Cs2215_Mpv_HedgeQtyLookupPerformance</project>
                        <area>Others</area>
                        <taskstatus>Closed</taskstatus>
                    </task>
                    <text>
                        Few small performance improvements in queries.
                    </text>
                    <notes>
                        <note>
                            <section>Info</section>
                            <component></component>
                            <text></text>
                        </note>
                    </notes>
                </checkintext>
            </Comments>
            <Components>
                <Component>
                    <Name>CsMpvCalcMatQtyHedgeBase.xpo</Name>
                    <Type>Classes</Type>
                    <Action>Edit</Action>
                    <Models>
                        <Model Id="I4C" Layer="ISV" />
                    </Models>
                </Component>
                <Component>
                    <Name>CsMpvInsertMatQtyDetails_Agreement.xpo</Name>
                    <Type>Classes</Type>
                    <Action>Edit</Action>
                    <Models>
                        <Model Id="I4C" Layer="ISV" />
                    </Models>
                </Component>
                <Component>
                    <Name>Cs2215_Mpv_HedgeQtyLookupPerformance.xpo</Name>
                    <Type>Shared</Type>
                    <Action>Add</Action>
                    <Models />
                </Component>
            </Components>
        </ChangeSet>
    </ChangeSets>
</ReleaseNotes>
```

HOw to find the attribute value Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have to use XPath? Can you just use a LINQ to XML query? Personally I find those easier to understand, though some don't...

Comment: @JonSkeet That's entirely a matter of taste I'd say :-).

Comment: @MathiasMüller: I don't think it's *entirely* a matter of taste. For example, consider the XPath expression the OP is using - that's potentially vulnerable to an "XPath injection attack" just like including values directly in SQL. It's much harder for that to be a problem in LINQ to XML. I also suspect that anyone with general XML and LINQ experience would be able to understand the LINQ to XML equivalent - no XPath-specific knowledge required.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did not mention using XPath expressions directly vs. preventing injections, but you're right of course, that could be an issue. And yes, people with LINQ experience understand LINQ to XML without XPath-specific knowledge - and people with XPath experience understand XPath without LINQ-specific knowledge. Anyway, I didn't mean to be argumentative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also work.

```
//ChangeSet[.//id[text()='CS-2215']]
```

Gets all changesets who has a child id with a specific text

Comment: Yes, but you should avoid `//` (`descendant-or-self::`) if the structure of the document is statically known. There is no reason to have brevity but possibly sacrifice efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
ReleaseNotes/ChangeSets/ChangeSet[Comments/checkintext/task/id[text()='CS-2215']]
```

*(Note: I used [an online XPath fiddle tool](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) to find this.)*

Comment: Sorry for being nit-picking, change `id[text()='CS-2215']` to `id ='CS-2215'`, since the string value of `id` is evaluated anyway. And I think the OP is looking for the ID value of that `ChangeSet`, so add `/@Id` at the end.